# MySQL Dump Not Working In MySQL

Tags: mysql

I just installed a new Windows 7 Professional machine with MySQL 5.6.22. When trying to run the mysqldump command, I get the following:

E:>mysqldump -u root -p world > world.sql
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'

Mysqldump works fine on my other machines running 5.16.15 and 5.5.xx. 
Unfortunately, the msi installer for MySQL 5.6.15 will  not work as some packages cannot be found. Oracle, it seems, will not support previous editions of 5.6.

On top of that, the MySQL installer for 5.6.23 only installs 5.6.22 in a round about way. The MSI installer has issues.

Can anyone shed light on mysqldump not working in 5.6.22?

Thanks!

Comment: Those errors are sometimes from a console alias (e.g., someone set up an alias which converts 'mysqldump' to 'mysqldump --no-beep'

Comment: I don't know about windows, but on linux you can type "alias" at the command prompt to see a list of aliases. You can type "alias | grep mysqldump" to see if any aliases for mysqldump are created. By the way, I've tried running mysql on WAMP and found it excruciatingly slow. Whereas installing a VMware Player virtual machine running ubuntu, on the same computer as where I had WAMP, ran MySQL blazingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the mysqldump command from the path it is installed, first cd into the folder and then run the command like this

```
C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqldump -u root -p -B database>name_of_backup_file.sql
```

Comment: The Path variable has the correct path. I did reset the machine. And applying the full path yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Search your active my.ini for the [client] section. Likely you will find the following:

```
[client]
no-beep
```

Comment or delete no-beep. It solves the 'no-beep' issue (now I have a new annoying error, hooray!). Be carefully checking whats your active my.ini because you might have some on different places.

**Edit:** Now, as I can call mysqldump w/o error, option --help tells me the follwing:
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf [Your Server DIR]\my.ini [Your Server DIR]\my.cnf